# Save non-eager tensor with tf.summary from tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Currently I want to save images during training from `tf.keras.model`. Keras disables eager execution, when compile and fit is used. However, the `tf.summary.image` expects an eager tensor, but when I use callbacks I only get non-eager tensors.

Here is a [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28868) post with working code example. Does someone know a workaround for this problem?